# Android Room: DAOs bigger than 1048576

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database

I have 11Mb JSON file and these file will be write on Dao but when I save all data. I got this error;

```
/data/user/0/com.test.save/databases/ChannelDb-wal 6946352 bytes: Bigger than 1048576; truncating
```

My codes;

```
AppDatabase dbRoom = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
        AppDatabase.class, Constants.CHANNEL_DB).build();

AndroidNetworking.get(user.getRemote())
        .setTag(Constants.GET_CHANNEL_LIST)
        .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
        .build()
        .getAsOkHttpResponseAndParsed(new TypeToken<List<Channel>>() {
        }, new OkHttpResponseAndParsedRequestListener<List<Channel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response okHttpResponse, List<Channel> channels) {
                AsyncTask.execute(() -> dbRoom.channelDao().insertAll(channels));
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ANError anError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Check 4");
                hideProgress();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.an_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Crashlytics.log(Log.DEBUG, TAG, anError.getErrorDetail());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this [WAL](https://sqlite.org/wal.html) has a limit of 1MB set, while the cursor-window on Android has a hard limit of 2MB.

therefore it is rather pointless, what you are trying to accomplish, even if disabling the `WAL`.

because even if you'd manage to somehow insert, you're not able to retrieve that again.

basically, you have two plausible options available:

a) parse the JSON and add it as individual records or

b) save the file to file-system and store it's path.